# webmethod takes too long to return results

Tags: jquery, ajax, mongodb, autocomplete

I wrote an autocomplete script that works very fast, but when I deployed it to IIS it takes 28s whenever I type a new letter. What am I doing wrong?

I'm using Ajax and jQuery for all this

The code for my method is as follow:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string[] GetCustomers(string prefix)
    {
        string connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
        MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(new MongoUrl(connectionString));

        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(settings);
        var _database = mongoClient.GetDatabase("test");


        IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("mycollection");

        var filter = new BsonDocument { { "name", new BsonDocument { { "$regex", prefix }, { "$options", "i" } } } };
        var sort = Builders<BsonDocument>.Sort.Descending("mycolumn");
        var fields = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Include("name").Include("anothercolumn");

        var c = collection.Find(filter).Sort(sort).Project(fields).Limit(10).ToList(); // or toCursor
        List<string> customers = new List<string>();

        foreach (var document in c)  
        {
             document.Elements.ElementAt(2).Value, document.Elements.ElementAt(1).Value));

        }

        return customers.ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

ok - found the solution. issue was related to the .Sort() method. it was taking a while to return results. just removed it. it solved the problem